# Match row names and sum-up their score across all columns in r

Tags: r

I want take a feature from reference column and search through all columns in dataset and sum up their corresponding value of features.
I have dataset like this:

```
  Reference        X1                X2         X3             X4
  Feature A       Feature A         0.99    Feature A         0.99                  
  Feature B       Feature B         0.77    Feature C         0.89                      
  Feature C       Feature C         0.89    Feature D         0.65
  Feature D       Feature D         0.65    Feature B         0.77                      
  Feature E
```

I want to make a new dataframe with feature name and their sum up score.
for example a new data frame i want like this:

```
Feature column             Score
Feature A                  1.98
Feature B                  1.54
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little complex because of the format of your data, but you could do

```r
result <- sapply(df$Reference, function(i) {
  sum(as.numeric(df[do.call(rbind, 
  lapply(seq_along(df[-1]), function(j) {
    if(any(df[[j + 1]] == i)) {
      rows <- which(df[[j + 1]] == i)
      cbind(rows, rep(j + 2, length(rows)))
    } else NULL}))]))
  })

data.frame(Feature = names(result), Score = c(result), row.names = NULL)
#>     Feature Score
#> 1 Feature A  1.98
#> 2 Feature B  1.54
#> 3 Feature C  1.78
#> 4 Feature D  1.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
 stack(tapply(as.matrix(df1[c(3, 5)]), as.matrix(df1[c(2, 4)]), FUN = sum))[2:1]
        ind values
1 Feature A   1.98
2 Feature B   1.54
3 Feature C   1.78
4 Feature D   1.30
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Reference = c("Feature A", "Feature B", "Feature C", 
"Feature D"), X1 = c("Feature A", "Feature B", "Feature C", "Feature D"
), X2 = c(0.99, 0.77, 0.89, 0.65), X3 = c("Feature A", "Feature C", 
"Feature D", "Feature B"), X4 = c(0.99, 0.89, 0.65, 0.77)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```